# how to fix .bash_profile? pip3 is not installing packages to Anaconda Python (Mac OS 10.15.4)

Tags: bash, pip, anaconda

After installing new packages using pip3 in my Conda env, I am not able to importing them in jupyter.

```
(base) MacBook-Air:~ johnsmith$ which python

/usr/bin/python
```

Looking at other posts, I understand this means that my default python is not the condo python install so I'm not getting the packages installed to the correct location.  Also looking at other posts, I think I might need to fix my .bash_profile file to point pip3 to the right python version.  Unfortunately, the file looks messy with several conda initializations.  Maybe these are leftovers from previous condo installs.  How do I fix this bash file? (I changed the user name but otherwise the file is identical).

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/johnsmith/homework/mjpro131/bin
export PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
# . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"  # commented out by conda initialize
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: This is why I wish installers wouldn't inject code into people's configuration files. It looks like you installed your own, newer version of Conda after previously using a system-wide installation. You can probably just remove the first block, delimited by the `conda init` lines.

Comment: Can you give us the output of `echo $CONDA_EXE`

Comment: /Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda

Comment: @chepner.  deleting the first conda init segment seemed to have fixed the python version.  now `which python` gives `/Users/johnsmith/opt/anaconda3/envs/pdf/bin/python`.  Unfortunately pip3 install still doesn't want to install to anaconda `python: already satisfied: portion in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.0.2)`  Any ideas about next steps?

Comment: Conda does not alias `pip` to `pip3` (or `pip2`), so likely by using `pip3` you are installing in some system-level Python installation (try checking `which pip3`). If you need to install from PyPI (or local source/GitHub) in a Conda env, it is always done with `pip`.